# Copy just two columns from one DataFrame to another in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a DataFrame with shape of (418, 13) and I want to just copy the two columns into a new DataFrame for outputting to a csv file. (I am writing a prediction)

```py
csv_pred = prediction[["PassengerId", "Survived"]].copy()
csv_pred.to_csv('n.csv')
```

However when I look into the outputted csv file I see this:

```
,PassengerId,Survived
0,892,0
1,893,1
2,894,0
. . .
. . .
```

instead of what I expected which is:

```
"PassengerId","Survived"
892,0
893,1
894,0
```

Does anyone know why my code doesn't work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the first column in the output csv file is the default index in your dataframe. If you do not want the index column, in df.to_csv() function set 'index = False', if you also do not want column labels set 'header = False'

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to create a new DF:

```
prediction[["PassengerId", "Survived"]].to_csv('/path/to/file.csv', index=False)
```